# Angularjs - how to add a row dynamically when clicked on parent row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and stuck with the below problem.

There will be a table of rows created which reads data from JSON. Say there are 6 rows displayed.But in real time number rows will vary.

Each row has an accordion(+ symbol) in its first td. If this accordian is clicked then the children rows of that row should be displayed by reading the data from one more different JSON.

Similarly for the remaining 5 rows as well it should display the children rows for the respective row's accordion is clicked.

I have created the table with the 6 rows displayed.
But the challenge I am facing is how to link child rows to the existing rows dynamically when clicked. Here is the plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/FTbjn9ZbAOTqc3b6j52h?p=preview

Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="treeTable">

<hr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="save()">SaveFilter</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-Default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>
<div  class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<div style=" margin-left:50px;" class="tableheight">
  <table class="table-nested ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th >
          <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
        </th> -->

        <th>
        Repository
        </th>
        <th >
          Version
        </th>
        <th >
          Size
        </th>
        <th >
        Modified By
        </th>
        <th >
        Labels
        </th>
        <th >
        Description
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  style="font-size:12px"  data-ng-repeat="item in list">
    <tr >
      <td  ><button style="background-color: #fff;" class="accordion"></button>
       {{item.name}}
      </td>

      <td >
        {{item.Version}} 
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Size}}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.ModifiedBy}}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Labels}}
      </td>
      <td >
        {{item.Description}}
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't made it clear which children should go with which repo.

Comment: @sh0ber Added the exact requirement image to the question. On clicking of the + link how can i add the row dynamically and display the contents which i get from different json. Let me know if you need more clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the Plunkr solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/BggZU1f4faEONUpXr6Ve?p=preview)

You want a 2nd `<tr>` with `ng-repeat` following the first:

```
<tr ng-if="item.Labels==child.Labels" ng-show="item.opened" ng-repeat="child in children">
    <td>{{child.name}}</td>
    ...etc
</tr>
```

This will build additional rows where the bundle `.Labels` matches the repo `.Labels` and will be shown only when the repo's `opened` property is `true`.  The `+` button will toggle the `opened` property for each item.  You'll need two minor edits to your data to make this work:

1. Add `children` data to the `$scope` (for access in the 2nd `ng-repeat`).
2. Add default `opened: false` property to all repos (except the first, which is `true`).

This won't show the components, but hopefully you get the idea.

[See the Plunkr solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/BggZU1f4faEONUpXr6Ve?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to add components to the second tr tag in the solution provided by you. I am unable to loop components to the corresponding bundle. There are syntax errors after i changed the code. My exact problem is unable to link multiple components to a single bundle. Please suggest.

Comment: Upvote this answer (as well as accepting it) and then ask a new question :)  Basically you'll need a 3rd `tr` to loop components.

Comment: upvoted! Where i need to add the 3rd tr? For every loop of bundle(ie. 2nd tr i need to loop for components also). Unable to add 3rd tr in 2nd tr tag. Please help me out.

Comment: The problem is that consecutive table rows are a really bad way of displaying nested parent/child data, since rows cannot contain other rows. It would be far better to display the nested data more logically, such as by including info about the components in one of the `tds` or something.  Or, to not use a table at all, and to repeat `divs` which *can* contain child `divs`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inset row after row clicked use this:

```html
<style>
    #tableid {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #tableid .childRow {
        font-size:10px;
    }

    #tableid .childRow td:first-of-type {
        padding-left:10px;
    }
</style>
<table id="tableid">
    <tr onclick="AddRow(this)">
        <td>abcd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    
    function AddRow(e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var index = e.rowIndex;
            var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
            var row = table.insertRow(index + 1 + i);
            row.setAttribute('class', 'childRow');
            var cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML = "efgh";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how will i add if i have multiple rows to insert?

Comment: I edited my answer to add each number you want. And a class for child rows that you can set another styles for them.